# Do we need to define graphic design in order to define graphicdesign.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

While the beta is at a very early stage, there are a lot of questions which seems to come under the heading of 'anything about graphics' rather than what I understand as graphic design.

It occurs to me that the Area 51 definition rather depends on one's understanding of 'graphic design'.

Should we define it - and if so, how?

Answer (score 8):

Not necessarily.

I think the *site definition* is best formed from several [*on-topic definition*](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition) questions, from which we can start to form some sort of consensus about [What should our FAQ contain?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

Also, I think it is better to focus on defining *this site* rather than judging: "this is graphic design" and "that doesn't belong to graphic design".

Answer (score 2):

After seing the status and number of questions in these first days ... Broaden the topic a bit and relax it might be needed for surpassing beta. Dunno, maybe I am wrong. This as well might imply to have also a more relaxed closing criteria. Not meaning to leave the site in the wild, though...

Answer (score 1):

To be aware of more discussions and opinions about this, a bit to collect several questions related to this, would be convenient to read:

[Is 3D on-topic?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/is-3d-on-topic/19#19)

[Should this SE site include Technical Questions (IE Photoshop, etc)](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/should-this-se-site-include-technical-questions-ie-photoshop-etc)

Or if questions about [Blender](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/133/where-can-i-find-tutorial-for-blender-closed) or 3D in general are ok to be closed, etc.