# Are modelling questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I've got some questions regarding modelling in maya and wanted to know if this is the right SE site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this question](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/is-3d-on-topic) probably not. Unfortunately there is no 3DSE anymore, the last one was shut down after 32 days in beta status..

Comment: I'm aware of the now defunct SE site - The problem is, there's a pretty big gap that's not covered by any of the SE sites now - Game Dev takes a similar stance. Very frustrating as I'm forced to resort to forums which seem lacklustre in comparison.

Comment: Hang in there. So far, no-one's come up with a reason we shouldn't include 3D design work. See http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/288/proposal-to-update-the-faq for more.