# Please help choose a new blurb for GraphicDesign!

Tags: discussion

This is the current "blurb" for GD:

> ## Graphic Design
>
> Q&A for professional graphic designers and non-designers trying to do their own graphic design
>   [image: Screen capture of the blurb as it appears on StackExchange lists]

As [**per this discussion,**](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/our-site-blurb-a-little-well-measly) it seems there is agreement with not liking the "trying"-bit. We not only try, we do!

So. To get this changed, we need overwhelming majority. To make this simple, feel free to suggest options, but ***only one per answer*** so that we can vote properly.

---

[Here you can see how other SE sites do it.](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic)

---

> I can get this changed for you guys as long as there's overwhelming
>   consensus. I need to see more than two votes on the proposed solution
>   before I can make the change. –  Abby T. Miller♦

**NOTE: Please only use UPVOTES and no downvotes, because not everyone uses them and they would mess up the numbers a little.**

Comment: "Do or do not do, there is no try" - Yoda

Comment: I think there should be another stage to this with more discussion, between the top voted answers; *unless* there's a clear winner.

Comment: @ckpepper02 do, do not or delegate. there is no try.

Comment: @Dominic I think there will not be a clear winner at this stage. You're right. I think we may need to wait and take 3-5 top answers here (all above 15 votes, to be sure), and continue with a vote on ONLY those top choices.

Comment: This will not happen quickly, I predict.

Answer (score 14):

### Q&A for Graphic Design professionals, students, and enthusiasts

Kind of like [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)'s tag:

> Q&A for electronics and electrical engineering professionals,
>   students, and enthusiasts

Comment: I don't think we want "people trying" - that's the whole point of the change. It sounds.. weird. To me, and to all of those supporting the change really, since it's the basis for the change. @Dominic

Comment: I like this, second to "Q&A for graphic design enthusiasts" - It seems that enthusiasts cover students and professionals as well.

Comment: Enthusiasts= people trying. Or close enough at least...

Comment: I see nothing gained by having "students" in there. Can't vote for it.

Comment: Three items (professionals, students, *and* enthusiasts) kinda makes it sound like we're making a list.  But this has my vote anyway.

Comment: If this is the preferred approach how about **"...for Graphic Design professionals and learners"**? Since we don't care why people are trying to learn to do good design, just that they ARE trying to learn.

Comment: "Enthusiasts" implies people that want to learn, not the ones begging for free designs. That is what we want.

Comment: I like this. Could perhaps add 'scholars' but that's being nit-picky.

Answer (score 5):

I will start out, "stealing" @user568458 alternative number 2:

### Q&A for design, illustration, and typography

My argument is that it covers pretty much everything and it is short. Short is *very* good.

Comment: illustration is missing a comma :) And including illustration is an interesting option as well. I look forward to seeing how it's voted.

Comment: @JonathanTodd Not to be too picky, but it is standard to omit the comma when "and" or "or" separate the last two items in a list. Of the coordinating conjunctions, the exception is "but," although even here, omitting the comma is no longer unacceptable.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson I had a very in-depth discussion with my English IV teacher on the matter. Apparently it is not a standard, but rather, a matter of disagreement, on which there seems to be no consensus. http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/052709serialcomma.htm

Comment: As I mentioned in user's post I'm still concerned about the lack of other topics. The more we list, the more we leave out.

Comment: @Ryan SO uses `Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers` - Being one of the most successful sites in the world, I believe we should follow their example, being short and concise. But you have a point: **this option, by being specific, causes other topics to seem less important**

Comment: I agree with Ryan, three points and beyond starts to sound like "These things and nothing else"

Comment: @JonathanTodd StackOverflow also has one of the most strictly enforced narrow scopes of any community in the world, so we might not want to follow them all the way. SO is successful because there's always been a massive gaping need for a good Q&A site in their profession, more so than probably any other profession.

Comment: FOR THE LOVE OF LITTLE GREEN APPLES, PUT IN THE SERIAL COMMA, PLEASE.

Comment: Also, how about "graphic design, illustration, and typography"? Or is it obvious that "Graphic Design" doesn't cover furniture and textiles?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I think something weird occurs when you put subcategories side by side with their parent. I mean, illustration and typography *are part of* graphic design. Also, I agree with the others here, being so broad makes it seem narrow.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I hate the Oxford Comma! 'Bout to get real up in here!

Comment: @Ryan Oh helllll no you di'unt just say that! hold me back! :D

Comment: @Dominic Yes, those three items are part of graphic design. But if you don't want to include any subcategories, why have a blurb at all? Which wouldn't bother me, honestly.

Comment: Dominic: I'll fetch the comma splicer. You see that participle @Ryan's dangling? It's about to get FUSED. ;)

Comment: You tie him up and I'll remove all of the punctuation keys from his keyboard. ;) We'll show him!

Comment: @LaurenIpsum The same way SO uses a single broad term in theirs, we can do so as well. Graphic design covers exactly everything that we do. I'm not sure why no one seems to be for that. "Q&A for graphic design enthusiasts" seems just right to me

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Well I think it should be semi-colons everywhere. **Q&A for design; illustration; and typography;**

Comment: @user568458 Your enthusiasm is commendable, if misplaced. :)

Comment: @JonathanTodd Don't misunderstand me. I said it's standard, which is not the same as "a standard." When we say something is standard, we mean it is accepted by literate readers and good writers, not that it's a rule.

Comment: @Random why is short *very* good?

Comment: @user mainly, by looking at the list of blurbs from other SE sites. Some of them are clunky, unnecessary cumbersome. If your site is called Graphic design, then that contains the essence. If your site is called "Database Administration", I do not think you need to add "_Q&A for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community_". And I agree on the argument that it is more important to say _what_ we deal with rather than _who_ we are.

Comment: I think overall it's important to summarise our purpose as best as we possibly can regardless of whether long or short. After all is said and done though, this is like our metatag description, and we should consider mostly from the SEO point of view - no one else that's already here bothers to read it. One thing that matters more than anything is the keywords we choose, and if I were voting solely on that basis and without any personal preference, my votes would be different here.

Comment: I agree that SEO is a large consideration. Though I do not think the one with the most votes is the best one, I have no objections. I think the important think is to get a new one. Anything is better than what we currently have, and the energy that has gone into this already seems sufficient :)

Answer (score 4):

### Q&A for graphic design professionals and enthusiasts.

Nothing new here, but I wasn't quite satisfied with the current options..

The middle ground between
**Q&A for graphic design professionals, students, and enthusiasts**
and
**Q&A for graphic design enthusiasts.**

And a minor rewording of this one
**Q&A for professional and enthusiast graphic designers.**

Answer (score 4):

I would add “visual communication” into the mix…

> ### Graphic Design
>
> ***Q&A for graphic designers and those interested in visual communication.***

Comment: Anything with the word Visual Communication gets my vote!

Answer (score 3):

### Q&A for the art of design

Short, snappy, and makes it sound like we've got an appropriately broad scope.

Implies that we welcome traditional art and "theory of design" questions - which we do! All the classic graphics stuff is obvious from our name.

Slightly stolen from Dominic's suggestion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'll appear next to "Graphic Design" everywhere it appears, so I don't think we need to duplicate the site name.

Answer (score 2):

#### Q&A for anyone interested in the art of graphic design.

Comment: Not bad, but graphic design is more than an art. It's also a business. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Q&A for graphic design enthusiasts.

Comment: I'll vote this one up, it's concise.

Comment: Don't like this one, sounds like it's implying "...and not professionals"

Answer (score 1):

### Q&A for the wonderful world of graphic design, and all creatures in it.

Comment: In my opinion, too silly.

Comment: All creatures 1024px and 320px?

Comment: @Dominic I can haz that on t-shirt pleeze? kthxbai

Answer (score 1):

#### Professional design Q&A for graphic designers, hobbyists and enthusiasts to share knowledge and learn from each other.

Answer (score 1):

#### Graphic design Q&A for professionals, hobbyists and enthusiasts to share knowledge and learn from each other.

Answer (score 0):

### Q&A for graphic designers, by graphic designers.

Comment: My only concern about this one is that we are leaving "people who want to do their own design" out.

Comment: @Yisela Yes it is a bit elitist, and I feel most of the short ones are wasting an important opportunity, I'll try to improve them

Answer (score 0):

### Q&A for professional, hobbyist and enthusiast graphic designers; fusing experience, knowledge and wisdom to practical solutions.

Comment: Too long; and as @user568458 pointed out; it might a good idea to put the emphasis on what we _do_ not _who we are_.

Comment: @Random its far from perfect but I personally think it's closer to the kind of word count we should be aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

## Q&A for people creating and developing graphics at any skill level.

Answer (score 0):

### Q&A for the Graphic Design community.

Answer (score -1):

user56's preferred choice "Q&A for design and artworking", in a more culture-neutral wording

### Q&A for design and artistry

A short option that simply covers everything

Comment: I actually like this; it is different, surprising and wonderfully short (in my head, "artistry" is connected to _artisan_ and to the phrase "with grace and artistry". All good associations).

Comment: We can thank user56 for the basic idea. His simply needed a rewording.

Comment: My problem with this is I think it kind of paints a different picture of the site to the one I see. "Design and artistry" sounds like questions about drawing technique and water-colour painting would be at home here, and perhaps they are (I'm not sure). But to me this site is very much focused on digital art, and neither of those words convey that to me.

Answer (score -1):

### Q&A for graphic design and digital artwork

Comment: Noo! This will encourage the Adobe Help Center questions :P They are necessary, but we already get enough of them

Comment: Why would it encourage adobe questions more than other options? Because of "artwork"? I don't see it!

Comment: @Yisela Mostly joking - the word "digital art" makes me immediately think "Adobe" though

Comment: @Dominic yep, I down-voted two, but not this one. Now, I can't withdraw the votes without voting opposite

Comment: Yeah it sounds like we only accept *digital* artwork questions

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, every other option goes too far

### Q&A for professional and enthusiast graphic designers

StackOverflow: Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers

---

- We don't need to specify subcategories next to the parent category, **("typography" and "illustration", for example, are all part of graphic design)**, and we don't need to elaborate.
- Stack Overflow does it best, yes it has a very defined scope, but it **has hundreds of sub categories within that scope**, and its blurb covers it all.

---

- **This covers everything without deviating into sub categories.**
- **"enthusiasts"** covers **"people trying"** and more.

Comment: If we have to have a blurb, this and "for graphic design enthusiasts" are the most concise without being limiting.

Comment: But these sites are part of a set, all with the same format, the same parent, and the same template. What's the problem with being a **custom version** of that **great template**? @Dominic

Comment: I like this one but I don't like that 'graphic design' is the last two words in the sentence. I'd expect the main topic to directly follow "Q&A for...". At a glance, I read "Q&A for professionals".

Comment: @Yisela It's the exact same as SO's. Is theirs bad in your opinion?? :P

Comment: @JonathanTodd As a google search description ("Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers". That IS makes a difference!) it's good, as a floating entity I don't entirely like it.

Answer (score -2):

## Graphic Design

**Q&A for professional graphic designers and anyone who wants to integrate principles of good design in their work.**

---

- The "Q&A for (people)" structure is used across all Stack Exchange sites, so the principle of parallel design suggests we maintain a consistent structure.
- The site is open to anyone: professional or student, design enthusiast or design-phobic.
- However, "professional graphic designers" is listed first, emphasizing that this is the target membership.
- Further, the mention of design *principles* references the [on-topic rules](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): questions should ask why design choices are made, not simply how to do it.