# Why do we have a solidworks tag?

Tags: discussion

Lately ive noticed the raise of solidworks related questions. I can se how this might be relevant in corner cases. Mainly though the questions are not really good fit. Because

- We dont have the exprtise, and personally i dont think cad how to's belong here when some adobe help questions do not either.
- They are mostly hit and run questions because we deal in 3D sometimes

Comment: Think you made a typo to either "they deal in 3D" or "we deal in 2d" so edited your question. Feel free to rollback if I'm wrong on that.

Comment: @Ryan no no i meant that we tolerate 3d

Comment: Okay, that makes sense too with the inclusion of sometimes. Just didn't understand it before.

Comment: My work is generally solid. Not always but most of the time. I find squishy work doesn't go over well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the tag is used for corner cases alone. Similarly to 3D, someone might face a *graphic design* question when using the software, and that's why the tag is there (although I don't think solidworks is as related to design as 3D is).

That being said, I don't think any of the current questions tagged as [solidworks](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidworks) is a good fit, and this is reflected by the very low number of votes and answers they got, but then again, it might be related to the field. Citing [Alan Gilbertson](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/561/2857):

> We -- designers in general and gd.se in particular -- have to be
>   willing to embrace the technologies that get the job done.

This is the reason why we have this task. All tags that are not used for a certain period of time get deleted, so they are sort of self-cleaning. I think, however, that we might need to discuss if the possible cases are so little that Solidworks should considered off-topic.

Comment: I dont dispute this. Its just that some people dont look beyond tag here so i can ask questions.